# Prove there is an L-structure (M,I) such that it is equivalent to sigma and has infinitely many elements

Tags: logic

Let L be a language and let $\Sigma$ be a set of first-order L-sentences. Suppose that, for every
natural number k, there exists an L-structure (M,I) such that (M,I) $\models$ $\Sigma$ and M has
exactly k elements. Use the compactness theorem for first-order logic to prove that there
is an L-structure (M,I) such that (M,I) $\models$ $\Sigma$ and M has infinitely many elements.

Been a lil stuck on this question, I understand it somewhat but not sure how to incorporate the M being finite. One part that has struck out is that deductions must be finite.

Comment: An MSE search will show you that this question has been asked many time before. See. for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240622/how-to-finish-proof-that-t-has-an-infinite-model

Comment: Thank you! that answers my question :) wasn't too sure of what terminology to use to ask the question